# mongo regexp that does not match trailing newline

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm looking to validate the data in a mongo database. A certain field should always have 5 alphanumeric characters (capital letters only). I was hoping that I could find invalid patterns with a query like this:

```
db.collection.find({myfield:{$ne:null,$not:/^[A-Z0-9]{5}$/}}).count()
```

This works, but it matches fields like "ABCDE\n". Is it possible to construct a regular expression that will not match values with a trailing newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work

```
/^[A-Z0-9]{5}(?!\n)$/
```